# rpm NOKEY error on copied packages, can I remove this?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, rpm

I used yum --downloadonly to fetch a few php71 packages on "VM A". I need to copy these to a different VM, "VM B" and install them using rpm -ivh. However on the secon "VM B" it's complaining about an RSA signature.

```
Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID be1229cf: NOKEY
```

How can I remove this from the rpm packages so it will install on the second VM without needing the key? I would prefer to not have to use --nosignature

This is CenOS 7.1

Answer (score 0):

The recommended solution is to import that pubkey.

But you can also remove the signature using rpm --delsign *.rpm.

Adding the pubkey once is likely less effort than removing the signature.

YMMV, JMHO.